# Automated task using pymssql runs fine during the day- but not at night; why?

Tags: sql-server, database, automation, scheduled-tasks, pymssql

I have a web scraping job that needs to be executed each evening. Our company has a virtual machine with the "Windows Task Manager" application installed. So, I created a new task (i.e., an entry in task manager) to run every evening at 3 a.m.

Initially, the process did exactly as expected: it fetched the data and inserted them into our database. A few nights later, the website we were scraping from kept shutting down for maintenance, so I went into Task Manager, changed the time setting to start at 10:30 pm instead of 3:00 a.m., and waited until the next morning.

The script executed completely with no exception issues- but *nothing* was entered into the database! The task manager even said that the script ran completely, and it even took the usual amount of time to run, but alas, no new rows.

One might posit that there was no new data to fetch. However, When I execute the script manually from the command line (and kept the start date/end date the same), the script uploaded the usual ~10,000 rows into the database. So there is data- but it only gets written to the database when we launch the script manually during the day, and not when scheduled in the evening.

Does anyone know a potential reason as to why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

**Edited to add:**
I understand that this question might sound a little ridiculous, especially since from the surface, there doesn't seem to be a lone factor in determining the issue. If I could provide any further background information into the issue, feel free to ask.

Comment: These problems are always difficult to diagnose. Can you check with whoever runs your SQL Server installation to see if any processes run around that time that might cause table locks (index defragmentation, backups, imports, exports)? Do you have any `try` / `except` blocks in your code that you can remove which might be obfuscating an error?